# Графический ключ

Tags: c#, .net

Заинтересовался созданием графического ключа для своего нетбука с функцией "тач скрин". Поискал в гугле подобные программы и ничего не обнаружил. Подскажите, где можно найти что-то подобное хоть на каком-нибудь языке.

Comment: Если используете Windows 8, то уже есть встроенный механизм авторизации по картинке

Answer (score 1):

[Вот попробуйте](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JyKrx6Kx0A).

Запрос для поиска в гугле (если ссылка помрет): Gesture Delphi.

Так же есть программы для управления жестами мыши, думаю, тач они тоже поддерживают.

Запрос для поиска в гугле: управление компьютером жестами мыши.